# How to toggle icheck checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, icheck

I have 2 checkboxes (Yes / No ) with the plugin icheck (http://icheck.fronteed.com), and I want when ***Yes*** is checked ***No*** will be unchecked, and vice-versa.

```
  <label class="checkbox-inline i-checks"> <input asp-for="Yes" type="checkbox" id="myicheckboxid1"/> Yes </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline i-checks"> <input asp-for="No" type="checkbox" id="myicheckboxid2"/> No </label>
```

Javascript

```
    $('.i-checks').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly why we have radio buttons. Why not use them?

Comment: @Dekel comment is correct, but you can also use jQuery `toggle` - https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Hello Dekel, I don´t use radio buttons, because I need to make in some case checkboxes to be mandatory and in  others case no.

Comment: This toggling behavior wouldn't make sense in those cases, though.  You should use radio buttons where this toggling behavior would apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event listeners and listen for the `change` event. Then in the callback that runs when the event fires, change the property opposing checkbox to the opposite of the event value.

```js
var firstCheckbox = $('#myicheckboxid1');
var secondCheckbox = $('#myicheckboxid2');

firstCheckbox.prop('checked', true); // default
// you could also use iChecked to do this but it's fine to set with `prop`
// firstCheckbox.iCheck('check');

firstCheckbox.on('change', function(event) {
  secondCheckbox.prop('checked', !event.target.checked);
});

secondCheckbox.on('change', function(event) {
  firstCheckbox.prop('checked', !event.target.checked);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/flat/_all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/flat/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>

<label class="checkbox-inline i-checks"> <input asp-for="Yes" type="checkbox" id="myicheckboxid1"/> Yes </label>
<label class="checkbox-inline i-checks"> <input asp-for="No" type="checkbox" id="myicheckboxid2"/> No </label>
```

But seriously, you should consider a radio buttons :)

Comment: Rico , Thanks a lot. 5 stars.